# How to encode float array in java and decode in c++ for protobuf

Tags: java, c++, protocol-buffers

I use "bytes" in protobuf to store float array.
It can be encode in Java like the following code:

```
public static ByteString change2Bytes(float[] emb) {
    ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.allocate(4 * emb.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < emb.length; i++) {
        float amplitude =  emb[i];
        buff.putFloat(amplitude);
    }
    return ByteString.copyFrom(buff.array());
}
```

But how to decode it in C++ after reading the Bytes(String in C++) from protobuf?

Update

I use this way to convert is OK. Thanks a lot.

```
unsigned char buffer[byte_str.length()];
std::copy(byte_str.begin(), byte_str.end(), buffer);
float emb[64];
memcpy(&emb, &buffer, sizeof(buffer));
```

Comment: So you're using the raw bytes in protobuf? If so, then the data type in C++ should be float32_t. Use `memcpy` and maybe `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial#reading-a-message

Comment: I'd recommend using a `repeated` float field instead of a byte array.

Comment: question: *why* are you using `bytes` here? `repeated float` should be fine, and `[packed=true]` means that it is essentially treated as `bytes` *anyway* (packed encoding is assumed on proto3, or is opt-in on proto2)